# RatingBar Theme working in Marshmallow but not in Lollipop

Tags: android, android-styles, ratingbar

I am trying to style my RatingBar with the following code:

```
<style name="RatingBarfeed" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/duskYellow</item>
</style>
```

And in layout.xml I am using the following code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRatingBar
        android:theme="@style/RatingBarfeed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:paddingBottom="0.45dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/rating"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/rating"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/rating"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        android:rating="3.5"
        android:stepSize="0.5"/>
```

Its working fine in Marshmallow (check the screenshot)
[image]

But in Lollipop Theme is not working (check the screenshot)
[image]

Please Help...!!!!

Comment: change this `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"` to this `parent="Theme.AppCompat"`

Comment: already tried no change its the same

Comment: change this `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRatingBar` to this `RatingBar`. and check that work or not ??

Comment: already tried this too. Same issue nothing changes.

Comment: done this twice. Tried Invalidate Caches and Restart also.

Comment: I check there is bug in my case only `highlightColor` is not work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After much struggle I got my answer:
it should be `style="@style/RatingBarfeed"` instead of `android:theme+"@style/RatingBarfeed"`

For styling star fill, empty and partial color

```
android:progressTint="#F9BB28"
android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/white"
android:secondaryProgressTint="@color/white"
```

Final code should be like

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRatingBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        style="@style/RatingBarfeed"
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:progressTint="#F9BB28"
        android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:secondaryProgressTint="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/rating"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/rating"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/rating"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        android:rating="3.5"
        android:stepSize="0.1"/>
```

Style should be:

```
<style name="RatingBarfeed" parent="android:style/Widget.Material.RatingBar.Small">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/duskYellow</item>
</style>
```

Comment: @SagarChavada **High Five**

Comment: although this is a nice fix for lollipop it is only available from api 21