# RatingBar color difference on different devices

Tags: android, xml, ratingbar

I have a `RatingBar`

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRatingBar
            android:id="@+id/rating"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:isIndicator="false"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:rating="0.0"
            android:stepSize="1.0"
            android:theme="@style/RatingBar"/>
```

and style:

```
<style name="RatingBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/old_gray</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/yellow</item>
</style>
```

The problem is that this style is ignoring for some reasons:

Nexus 5x API 24:
[image]

Samsung S4 API 21:

[image]

My Activity is `extends FragmentActivity` maybe the problem is here? How to fix?

Comment: Create custom Rating bar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RatingBar Theme working in Marshmallow but not in Lollipop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39911082/ratingbar-theme-working-in-marshmallow-but-not-in-lollipop)

Answer (score 3):

**From API 21 and over** you can simply change it from xml

```
android:progressTint="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
android:progressBackgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
android:secondaryProgressTint="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally after much try I got the solution:
Instead of using `android:theme="@style/RatingBar"` use `style="@style/RatingBar"`

and use

`android:progressTint="yourColor"
 android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/yourColor"
 android:secondaryProgressTint="@color/yourColor"`

for fill, partial and empty color of star in rating bar. It will work same in both devices.

and your style should be

```
<style name="RatingBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Material.RatingBar.Small">
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/yourColor</item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/yourColor</item></style>
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to change the color of RatingBar according to device so firstly to find the version of device by

int  **androidVersion** = Integer.parseInt(android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE);
 after that

Drawable drawable = ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
    drawable.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#"+**androidVersion** /*Create_color_via_**androidVersion**_with_the_help_of_Random_JAVA_class*/), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

Answer (score 0):

Try to provide the same color for both **colorControlNormal** and **colorControlActivated**

```
<style name="RatingBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/yellow</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/yellow</item>
</style>
```

RESULT:
**1. On Nexus 5**
[image]
**2. On Samsung S4**
[image]

I don't know the reason why this is happening but you can have your result.

Answer (score -1):

```
public void setRatingBar(RatingBar ratingBar) {
    LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
    stars.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.rating_yellow), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    stars.getDrawable(0).setColorFilter(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.grey_text), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    stars.getDrawable(1).setColorFilter(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.rating_yellow), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
}
```

**use above method and set this to rating view as shown below before setting rate to rating bar.**

```
setRatingBar(ratingView);
```

**Add this to styles.xml**

```
<style name="RatingBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/grey_text</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/rating_yellow</item>
</style>
```

**and set this as a theme to rating bar**

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:isIndicator="true"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:scaleX="0.5"
    android:scaleY="0.5"
    android:stepSize="1"
    android:theme="@style/RatingBar" />
```

It works fine for me… Hope it works well for you also